# Is the cosmological Continuity Equation an expression for energy conservation in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion

Is the [cosmological continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations)

$$ \frac{d\rho}{dt} + 3H(\rho + p/c^2) = 0 $$

an expression for energy conservation in General Relativity?

Comment: Hi Rene. I've converted your equation to MathJax, but shouldn't the minus sight be a plus? We'd normally write $\dot\rho = -3H(\rho+p)$. And yes, that equation is essentially saying $T^{\alpha\beta}{}_{;\beta} = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is ! We can also understand this using the first law of thermodynamics as follows,

Considering the expansion of the homogeneous universe as an adiabatic process, we have,

\begin{equation}
dE + pdV = 0 \hspace{7mm} ;  \hspace{7mm}  \dot{E} + p\dot{V} = 0
\end{equation}

Assuming that the comoving volume is $ V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 a^3(t)$, we can find that $ \dot{V} = 3 V H $. Since $ E = \rho V$, we can write

\begin{equation}
\dot{E} = V \dot{\rho} + \rho \dot{V} = V \Big ( \dot{\rho} + 3 \rho \frac{\dot{a}}{a}\Big) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-3pV\frac{\dot{a}}{a} =  V \Big ( \dot{\rho} + 3 \rho \frac{\dot{a}}{a}\Big)  
\end{equation}

and finally, we get,

\begin{equation}
-3H \Big(p + \rho \Big)=  \dot{\rho}
\end{equation}